# Optimistic concurrency with Entity Framework and MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm currently developing an app using Entity Framework 4.1 and MySQL. I want to use optimistic concurrency and therefore need to create a table structure which allows EF to detect concurrency issues. My goal is something similar to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/20/tip-19-how-to-use-optimistic-concurrency-in-the-entity-framework.aspx.

My problem is that the timestamp-type is different in MySQL compared to MS SQL Server. In addition to that neither timestamp nor datetime offer sub-second precision in MySQL (http://feedblog.org/2007/05/26/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-datetime-resolution/). These types would therefore be quite bad in detecting concurrency-problems.

What other data-type could I use to solve this? I was thinking of maybe using a Guid. There are two potential problems with this approach though: 1. MySQL stores Guids as char(36) making them very inefficient. 2. I'm not sure if the EF requires the row-version to be strictly increasing or if it's enough that it's unique.

Comment: how complex is the system? could you, for example, use a pre-submit hook to increment an integer on the row (like a manually implemented, row-specific `ROWVERSION`)?

Comment: All insertions and updates are run through the same generic method so I could possibly increment the row-version there. However, the code could potentially run on several different machines so it could be hard to sync that across the servers.

Comment: you don't have to sync it, surely; if you are guarding against changes *inside* the unit of work, it should already be automatic; if you are holding the rowversion between calls (at the client), then just compare to the rowversion on the record you fetched...?

Comment: Cool, that was what I thought. I was just not sure exactly how the concurrency-checks were implemented in EF. So the only thing that's important is that you can detect updates after your fetch and this solution gives you that. Even though the updated rowversion in the context might be identical to the rowversion of the concurrently updated row in the database. Am I understanding things correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big caveat: ***NOT TESTED*** - just thinking aloud.

EF supports override of [`SaveChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx), so perhaps one option is to define an interface such as:

```
interface IVersionedRow {
    int RowVersion {get;set;}
}
```

and add an `int RowVersion` property/field to both your model class(es) and the database table(s), and use `partial class` to implement this interface (using implicit interface implementation):

```
partial class Customer : IVersionedRow {}
partial class Order : IVersionedRow {}
...
```

Then override `SaveChanges`, something like:

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{    
    foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
        ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified))
    {
        var v = entry.Entity as IVersionedRow;
        if(v != null) v.RowVersion++;
    }
    return base.SaveChanges(options);
}
```

that should then function (in theory - untested) as a manually implemented row-version counter. Leave change-validation enabled for `RowVersion`, and that should serve.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! What would happen if two separate contexts run the code concurrently? Any potential issues with the increment-operation not being synced across the different contexts?

Comment: @Yrlec for a row-version, you don't *want* it to propagate between contexts - you want all but the first to edit a row to throw a big error message.

Comment: @Yrlec and to answer the question; say the rowversion is currently 42; two threads get that record and try to save as 43; but remember you left value-checking enabled for that column. So *one* of them is going to succeed (and change it from 42 to 43), and the other is going to fail (because it demanded a 42 in the row, but found a 43 in its place). Which is what we want, no?

Comment: Hi! This did not work at all for, mysql version 8.0.30. All the queries which are generated still have rowversion param provided as 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is tested solution (for EF6 and above).

Here what you have to do in your model:

```
    [Table("some_table")]
    public class SomeEntity : IVersionedRow //define an interface as described previously and replace int type to long
    {
        ...
        [Column("row_version")]
        public long RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
        .Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{    
    var objectContextAdapter = this as IObjectContextAdapter;
    if (objectContextAdapter != null) {
        objectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified)) {
            var v = entry.Entity as IVersionedRow;
            if (v != null) 
                v.RowVersion++;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now when you do update or delete operation don't forget to include [DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception(v=vs.113).aspx) . It works perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have just submitted a [PR to MySQL .NET Connector v6.9.10](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/pull/23) that provides a solution for this issue that provides optimistic locking between EF and non-EF applications.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147396/365261 for details.