# entity framework 6 mysql rowversion

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 with my sql and seems like row version byte array is not supported by mysql.
any help how this can be achieved.

```
[Column(TypeName = "timestamp")]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm using solution described **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39760766/3278271)** and so far no issue. Everything works right.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you are using automatic migration I think that the property attributes are not enough to create the right field type.
Here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html there are the syntax that EF provider should generate to create a timestamp that is automatically generated/updated.

After creating the right field type you could do 2 tries:

-Mark the field as Timestamp

```
[Timestamp]
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

I don't think that EF needs that a Timestamp field is byte[]. Timestamp should only mean that is database generated field and that the optimistic concurrency use that field (i.e. update queries contains a where on the keys of the record to update and this field). But often EF does not work as I think...

-Mark the field as generated by database and as a field to use to check for optimistic concurrency exceptions

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, if you use a `DateTime` value for optimistic locking it can fail due to loss of precision in the Oracle MySQL driver. There are [bug reports](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73271) on this that are years old that apparently they are refusing to fix.

**Update:** I have just submitted a [PR to MySQL .NET Connector v6.9.10](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/pull/23) that provides a solution for this issue that provides optimistic locking between EF and non-EF applications.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147396/365261 for more details.

As a workaround, you can create your own Non-DATETIME optimistic locking column.
By setting this value via DB trigger (rather in c# code) we ensure that it works for external apps and any DB admin tasks.

- Add column `rowversion BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,`
- Add a trigger to set this field to random or sequential value.
- Add E6 attributes on the new column.

#### Sequential rowversion

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_mytable_before_update` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `mytable` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`rowversion` = OLD.`rowversion` + 1;
```

#### Random rowversion

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_mytable_before_update` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `mytable` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`rowversion` = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * POW(2,54));
```

#### EF6 Attributes

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
[ConcurrencyCheck]
[Column("rowversion", TypeName = "bigint")]
public virtual long RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue, I fixed it by doing the following:

For MYSQL you must use DateTime as byte[] doesn't work

```
public DateTime RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Then on your context class, go to the OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
      builder.Entity<YourClass>()
           .Property(c => c.RowVersion)
           .HasColumnType("datetime(3)")
           .IsRequired()
           .IsRowVersion();
}
```

By setting the column type to datetime(3), it will store milliseconds as well, thus helping with the precision issue mentioned above.