# DELETE via linq throwing concurrency exception without concurrency

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Via linq while using entity framework, I'm removing data from a mysql db, it's a single thread program and nobody is working on db isntead of me. Every time that i try to remove entities via:

```
db.table.Remove(entity);
```

It throws a concurrency exception when i do `db.SaveChanges();` how is it possible?

Comment: LINQ is a query language. It doesn't make changes. Which ORM are you using? Entity Framework? What is the *actual* error? Post the *actual* code and the full exception including the call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: Concurrency doesn't mean threads. It means that *something* changed the data that you are trying to save. The ORM detected that when you called `SaveChanges` and warned you about it. If it hadn't, it would have overwritten the other changes

Comment: Yes sorry, i tought it was obvious, i'm using entity framework

Comment: Exactly that's the problem, there is nothing possibily changing the db instead of this program

Comment: Obviously there is. Post the code and the full exception. Check your data. Read about optimistic concurrency by the way to understand what's going on. Depending on how you configured the mapping, your code is either using a timestamp value to check for changes or the values of all properties.

Comment: Okay i found the problem, i will write it as answer cause i never saw it on stackoverflow ^^

Comment: Are you sure? I bet if you google for this you'll find duplicates. Optimistic concurrency isn't new. MySQL's timestamp column though isn't precise enough leading to problems that [require custom solutions](https://blog.hundeide.net/2015/05/optimistic-concurrency-with-mysql-and-entity-framework/). In the end, you may end up [overriding SaveChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608619/optimistic-concurrency-with-entity-framework-and-mysql)

Comment: It wasn't concurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find this problem on StackOverflow so I will post the solution because i found it by myself and the error wont lead you to a solution:

If you must do operations in a foreach, using a list of results took by your DB, and then you have to remove results

**Don't do that:**

```
List<Ducks> ducks = (from duck in db.Ducks select duck).ToList();
foreach (Ducks duck in ducks)
{
    //TODO
    db.Ducks.Remove(duck);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or you will get into concurrency errors.

You must remove entities out of their foreach.

**Solution:**

```
List<Ducks> ducks = (from duck in db.Ducks select duck).ToList();
foreach (Ducks duck in ducks)
{
    //TODO
}
db.Ducks.RemoveRange(ducks);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try
{
    db.table.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // Provide for exceptions.
}
```